# How To Un-Twist a Spiral STL Object?

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine

I have a cylinder-like spiral object as `.STL` file. There are edges responsible for being twisted (Highlighted in the image below). How can I un-twist it partially (or fully, so that I'd have a flat surface at the end)?

[image]

[image]

Edit:
What we want finally:
Compressed (left) vs Stretched (right)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The mesh is very messy so you can't really expect any tool to do a good job here. You can try Limited Dissolve (X-menu) and adjust the Angle and see if that works.
Otherwise it might be faster to remodel it.

Comment: I want to correspond a spring-like Bezier curve to the cylinder in order that the cylinder can be stretched or compressed like a spring. Before doing so, there is also a need to split the cylinder on highlighted edges. Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add a sketch so it could be a bit easier to understand this setup?

Comment: Hi, I added "What I finally want" in the question. Thank you.

Comment: The sketch helped a lot to describe the problem. I think it could be possible to do with a two bone armature and some careful wight painting. I have never done anything like this and I would expect it to take several attempts doning it. Possibly involving scripting.